# ImportError: cannot import name '_FunctionWrapper' from 'scipy._lib._util' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py)

Tags: python

I'm trying to transform wav files into MEI spectrograms.

My code is as follow :

```
import glob
import librosa
import mei

# Create an empty list to store the spectrograms
spectrograms = []

# Set the directory containing the WAV files
mydir = "/content/drive/My Drive/Musical Classification/gtzan-fixed/Data/genres_original/disco"

# Get a list of all WAV files in the directory
file_list = glob.glob(mydir + "/*.wav")

# Iterate over all WAV files in the list
for file in file_list:
  # Load the WAV file
  data, sample_rate = librosa.load(file, sr=None)

  # Create the MEI spectrogram
  spectrogram = mei.mei(data, sample_rate, 512)

  # Add the spectrogram to the list
  spectrograms.append(spectrogram)
```

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 import glob
----> 2 import librosa
3 import mei
4
5 # Create an empty list to store the spectrograms

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py in 
8 from scipy.optimize import OptimizeResult, minimize
9 from scipy.optimize._optimize import _status_message
---> 10 from scipy._lib._util import check_random_state, MapWrapper, _FunctionWrapper
11
12 from scipy.optimize._constraints import (Bounds, new_bounds_to_old,

ImportError: cannot import name '_FunctionWrapper' from 'scipy._lib._util' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py)

---

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.

Can you please help me thanks you.

I tried to uninstall it and reinstall it

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include the full error traceback?

Comment: This seems like a corrupted scipy installation. Can you uninstall scipy and then reinstall it? `pip uninstall scipy`. and then `pip install scipy`

Comment: I tried to done it, not sure

Comment: I have done that and its not working. i'm working with google collab if that helps